# is latest Socket IO not compatible with its older versions?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How to make a project made with socket io 1.1.0 compatible with socket io last version? it's my own project and i'm getting no error messages but stuff doesn't work as intended after updating so I have no idea what's going on

Answer (score 0):

read [socket.io migrating instruction](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#)

There are some changes in new socket.io

Comment: That's migrating from 0.9. I started my project with 1.1 and it works flawlessly with 1.1.

Comment: oh, sorry... I don't know about problems with newest socket.io I still use 1.1

Comment: I would rather burn in hell than work for free for people that makes me waste my time. Switching libraries right now ; )